# my solidity airdrop contract don't works

Tags: solidity, airdrop

I works in a last 3 days on solidity airdrop smart contract , i tried it on rinkeby but don't work. i try several time but fail and i dont know why.
[Here my last fail TX](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xbd4fe7e9a7e35d64a92b78549905af0a810b5548912ae4dff2b1cd5c66e6ca0b)

```
A total of 86 steps found.  Contract transaction successfully completed.  Note: REVERT opcode found.
```

Hope someone can help me?

[Here my code on test net](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/address/0x1a928924e68913433e2881444CaFA0271DbBd5ae#code)

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tx is reverted because of this line : `require(validPurchase(beneficiary));`

```
function validPurchase(address beneficiary) internal view returns (bool) {
    bool isWhitelisted = whitelisted[beneficiary]; <----
    bool hasParticipated = participated[beneficiary];

    return isWhitelisted && !hasParticipated;
}
```

`isWhitelisted` is `false`, because your addy `0x94672796f20fe52eedcef5a590395a9aeeb0fb48` is not whitelisted.

Comment: Thanks Will  i want to insert in my code the possibility to partceipated at airdrops only 1 times

Comment: Stop stealing my thunder @EliDrion